# SQL Server 2016 percentage of single column count in new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage, calculated-columns

I have to show percentages of each letter beside each letter value, or, for each letter, divides its count by 100, and list each fraction beside each letter value.

I can't do a normal aggregate sum or divide because I get distinct values for the letters, when I need the percentages beside them like below, if possible.

if my table.name column shows:

```
NAME
-----
a
b
b
c
c
c
d
d
d
d
```

What query can I use to show percentage of each letter in new column over 100, or where total is for each letter, e.g.:

```
NAME        Percentage
---------- --------------
a           100%
b           50%
b           50%
c           33%
c           33%
c           33%
d           25%
d           25%
d           25%
d           25%
```

This isn't meant to be a "homework" question but I wanted to see if anyone had any ideas of approach since this didn't seem to be common.

Thanks for any ideas you might have.

Comment: What have you tried so far?????  SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: So you want the result of 100 divided by the `COUNT` of each letter in the column? Or is the data in each row made up of characters with spaces requiring a `STRING_SPLIT` function? Either way, seems simple enough. What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @ZLK yes, so only one 'a' would correspond to a '100%' next to it, but 5 'e' would have a 20% beside each 'e', suggesting 100/count of each letter to a new column, if possible.
I am still playing around with it but I'm probably not using COUNT(name) in the right place because I'm getting distinct rows of each letter with a percentage or count beside it.

Comment: You should post what you're trying but 100 / COUNT(name) while grouping by the name would work.

Comment: because you are going to aggregate you don't actually need DISTINCT.  You should look at the GROUP BY clause instead

Comment: @indiri,@ZLK Apologies for any lack of clarity. My boss just change course and what you mentioned is appropriate. I was going for something more robust but it's better this way. I'll use 100/count(name) and enumerate out if needed, which was similar to how I started but was first rejected. Thanks for the input.

Comment: If you want them to still be in separate rows (no GROUP BY) you can do your percentage using Window Functions as well

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @a int,@b int,@st varchar(100),@result varchar(100),@current_char varchar(1)

set @st='abbbccddddd'
select @a=len(@st)
set @result=''
set @current_char=LEFT(@st,1)

while @a>0
BEGIN
select @result=@result+' '+left(@st,1)+' '+CAST(CAST(100.0/(LEN(@st) - LEN(REPLACE(@st,left(@st,1),''))) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5))+'%' 
set @current_char=LEFT(@st,1)
set @st=replace(@st,@current_char,'')
set @a=len(@st)
END

print @result
```